# Criteria query : order by count

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to do a criteria query that returns the most answered questions in an stackoverflow like faq.

A question contains multiple answers.

I'm trying to return with a criteria query the most answered questions ordered by number of answers per question.

Any one knows what should I use in the hibernate criteria util ?

Comment: Do you have working sql that you can post?

Comment: Nope. I dont even know how i would do this query in plain sql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Question.class, "q");
criteria.createAlias("q.answers", "answer", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("q.id"))
                                                   .add(Projections.count("answer.id").as("numberOfAnswers")));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("numberOfAnswers"));
```

This will return you a list of Object[]. Each Object[] contains the ID of the question as first element, and the number of answers of this question as second element. the questions are sorted by descending number of answers.

If you needs additional properties (example : question text), then add additional groupProperty projections (example : `add(Projections.groupProperty("q.text"))`)

The SQL corresponding to this criteria query looks like this :

```
select this_.ID_QUESTION as y0_, count(answer1_.ID_ANSWER) as y1_ from QUESTION this_ left outer join ANSWER answer1_ on this_.ID_QUESTION=answer1_.ID_QUESTION group by this_.ID_QUESTION order by y1_ desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in my case, in my mapping files, the only link between QUestion & Answer is a field with the id of the question. Is it possible to make the count query on the class where i would define the current Question id ?

Comment: Then your mapping is wrong. You definitely have a one to manny relationship between question and answers. Map this relationship like it should be, rather than using IDs. Hibernate is suppsed to work on an object model.

Comment: Depending on the number of question, it might be worth to keep track of the number of answers as a property of the question object (resulting in a column in database). Sorting on a column is much cheaper than sorting on the number of relations done by a join + count. However, this is a more error prone approach and the number of answers should be updated consistently for this to work.