# Sorting a Result Set by a Projected Aggregate Column

Tags: hibernate, sorting, groovy

I've been using Hibernate for some time now but I only come across to this scenario a while ago so here it goes. I have a parent-child Domain classes, say `Person` that can create one or many `Item`s, as so:

```
class Person {
    Integer id
    Integer craftingMaxCap
    String name

    static hasMany = [
        items: Item
    ]
}

class Item {
    Integer id
    String name 

    static belongsTo = [
        creator: Person
    ]
}
```

In the UI side, I show the Person's name, the current number of crafted item, and the maximum allowable craftable Item. While I do the pagination and sorting on the back-end.

While I can sort the first and last column easily as:

```
ArrayList<Person> data = Person.createCriteria().list {
    //...
    order("name", "asc")
    // or order("craftingMaxCap", "asc")
}
```

How can I sort the result set by the number of crafted item per person? I am able to show that column via `JSONMarshaller` but I cannot sort it. I am currently doing this by the tedious  `Collection.sort` method but I wonder if I can do this on the database side by utilizing Hibernate Projections, Groovy's closures, etc.

I had found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4971082/4043409) from a different question but I don't know how to implement the `Projections` with an alternative alias name in Groovy.